# Cannot connect FTP to Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, ftp, virtual-machine, filezilla

I provisioned a Windows Server 2012 vm in Azure. When I try to connect to it via FileZilla FTP client I get a `Could not connect to server error`.

Here's what I have tried so far:

- Added inbound rule for FTP (TCP/21) in the Azure portal
- In IIS, configured FTP Firewall Support. Set `Data Channel Port Range to 7000-7002`, `External IP Address of Firewall to my vm's public IP`, `added 7000, 7001 and 7002 to inbound rules`, `did a net start/stop ftpsvc`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl what does it mean to `locate three “FTP server” rules`? I don't seem to find one in the `Inbound Rules`. Screenshot here http://i68.tinypic.com/fmj7t5.png

Answer (score 1):

The step I'm missing in your description, is enabling *"FTP server"* rules in Windows firewall.

They are created during IIS server installation, but are disabled by default. You have to enable them.

Quoting my guide to [Installing a Secure FTP Server on Windows using IIS](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server#window_firewall):

> An internal Windows firewall is automatically configured with rules for the ports 21, 990 and 1024-65535, when IIS FTP server is installed.
>
> The rules are not enabled initially though. To enable or change the rules, go to *Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings > Inbound Rules* and locate three “FTP server” rules. If the rules are not enabled, click on *Actions > Enable Rule*.

[image: FTP server firewall rules]

---

If you do not have them, for whatever reason, you have to create them manually.  For port 21 and the data ports (in your case 7000-7002).