# FTP server in Azure VM will not connect from internet

Tags: azure, ftp

I cannot connect either to IIS FTP server or Filezilla FTP server externally, but it will work from within the VM (ftp://localhost).
My Azure VM works fine with RDP. NSLookup returns the VM's IP.
In the virtual network I have ports 21 and 22 (I ultimately need an SFTP server working, but now I am resolving network issues first) open for TCP inbound traffic. I also have ports 55000-55555 open for any traffic. I have default outbound rules open for any traffic any port.
The external IP is registered in the server and corresponding ports are open. I also have FTP open in the VM's firewall.
Filezilla client on my home machine cannot connect with any protocol, anonymous, or user.
I have followed every tutorial I can find.
Any guesses what I am still missing?

(I already followed the tutorial referred to in this question: [Cannot connect FTP to Azure virtual machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40885337/cannot-connect-ftp-to-azure-virtual-machine))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things to try:

- Can you connect to another FTP server from your client machine ? rule out any client outbound routing issues.
- Can you use START, RUN, TELENET IP PORT to connect to the public IP of the server? i.e 99.99.99.99 21 , is a useful test to ensure you get TCP connection on any listening port.
- Test from another clinet, do you have another VM you can test from too?
- Turn off Windows Server firewall briefly for testing.
- Examine VM the VM network secutity group and ensure inbound rules setup i.e Firewall rules and ensure inbound traffic is allowed on ports 20 and 21 (and 22).

Your test locally first from the server is the right idea , clearly proving the service is operating locally and the problem is firewall/routing related or on the client.

Comment: This is a good start for the troubleshooting, but i suggest using PowerShell and "Test-Netconnection -ComputerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -Port 21" instead, since you dont need to install Telnet that way. :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you to both of you! I used the PS test-netconnection and it worked. I turned the firewall on and off and it worked both times!! Not expecting that. I en/disabled rules to break/fix so I understand those better. I wonder if I tested changes in the vnet configurations too soon before they propagated? I made no changes except letting things sit overnight! Now I am on to SFTP. Any recommendations beside Solar Winds? Any special rules or setting somewhere to be aware of?